# How to show popup with progress bar using ajax and jquery in update panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I trying to show the modal pop using jQuery, ajax updateprocess with progress bar. I'm not good in both. I searched in google and got some example. This code is working without updatepanel. Please help me to work this code with updatepanel.

------------------code without updatepanel--------------

```
  <style type="text/css">
.modal
{
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 99;
     background-color: transparent;
    opacity: 0.8;
    filter: alpha(opacity=90);
    -moz-opacity: 0.8;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
.loading
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;


    position: fixed;
    background-color: transparent;
    z-index: 999;
}
```

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
function ShowProgress() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        var modal = $('<div />');
        modal.addClass("modal");
        $('body').append(modal);
        var loading = $(".loading");
        loading.show();
        var top = Math.max($(window).height() / 2 - loading[0].offsetHeight / 2, 0);
        var left = Math.max($(window).width() / 2 - loading[0].offsetWidth / 2, 0);
        loading.css({ top: top, left: left });
    }, 200);
}
```

```
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" onclick="btnInvoke_Click" OnClientClick="ShowProgress()"
                 runat="server" Text="Submit Time" Width="170px" />

                 <div class="loading" align="center" style="display:none">
                     <img src="images/a1.gif" alt="" />
                 </div>
```

---------------with update panel--------------

```
  <asp:UpdateProgress ID="updProgress" runat="server">
        <ProgressTemplate>
        <div class="loading" align="center" style="display:none">
                     <img src="images/a1.gif" alt="" />
                 </div>    
        </ProgressTemplate>
    </asp:UpdateProgress>

    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lblText" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            <br />

            <asp:Button ID="btnInvoke" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClientClick="ShowProgress()"
                onclick="btnInvoke_Click"  />

        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When I'm using updatepanel how can I close this popup and loader.please help me to write that jQuery.

Please suggest good example with popup with progress bar in updatepanel or any other way to do it.

Comment: I would try to lose the updatepanel.  I've had a lot of problems in the past when using UpdatePanels and mixing jQuery in there.  If you're using .Net, you can either call your code-behind functions from the script, by making them public webmethods or you can make an AJAX call to a webservice - and then manipulate the DOM accordingly.  You won't have any of these issues if you do that.  Otherwise, you need to rebind your events and refire your functions when the update panel is completely loaded, but as far as I know, there is no "event" to listen for indicating such.  Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

```
</asp:ScriptManager>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<Triggers> 
<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Button1" EventName="Click"/>
</Triggers>
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" 
 AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
```

```
  Update in Progress……..

 </ProgressTemplate>
  </asp:UpdateProgress>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" 
 OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
```